# ConstraintLayout's Flow vs. Fragments programaticaly

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I have `Flow` in my `ConstraintLayout` set up like this:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/subjects"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:flow_maxElementsWrap="2"
    app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="test1,test2,test3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pair_your_device_subtitle" />

<!-- The test ids are just simple Views with colorful background -->
```

And it works, the test views are arranged in 2 columns.

Now, I have list, wchich is transformed to Fragments and I want those Fragments to be arranged in this Flow.

So I have the code like following:

```kotlin
childFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
    object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
        override fun onFragmentViewCreated(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment, v: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            if (f is SnapshotFragment) {
                Timber.d("onFragmentViewCreated ${v.id}")
                require(v.id != View.NO_ID) // id is generated in SnapshotFragment with View.generateId()
                subjects.addView(v)

                // Testing
                subjects.addView(View(requireContext()).apply {
                    id = View.generateViewId()
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(400, 400)
                    background = ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(android.R.color.black))
                    constraint.addView(this)
                })
                Timber.d("onFragmentViewCreated ${subjects.referencedIds.asList()}")
            }
        }
    },
    false
)

childFragmentManager.commit {
    subjectsList.forEach { subject ->
        add(
            constraint.id,
            SnapshotFragment::class.java,
            bundleOf(SnapshotFragment.SUBJECT_KEY to subject)
        )
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work.

Well, the callbacks are called, the ids in logs looks good, the black testing views are added correctly, but the fragment's views are stuck at the top left corner.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159516508

This issue was the cause. When I changed view id generation from `onViewCreated()` directly to `onCreateView()`, it started working.